# Node: unable to get issuer certificate with axios

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios, ssl-certificate

I'm getting an `unable to get issuer certificate` error when trying to connect to a server (I'm already using and providing a custom CA). The error message doesn't have the word "local" in it, so it seems different from self-signed errors where no CA at all is given.

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed different, comes from this error code in openssl:

> 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT': Unable to get issuer certificate.

OpenSSL manual says that means you are providing the wrong CA. This wound up being the case. I thought I had the root CA listed, but it was only the intermediate cert. In this case I needed to find the root cert from a different source, then it passed the check.

The following code wound up working.

```
const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    ca: ["...cert text..."],
  }),
};
await axios.get(url, options);
```

Comment: what is cert text?  Where can I find more information on what is a root CA, a intermediate cert, etc?